# Multiple buttons in a Manipulate: how do I get a good layout?

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction, button

Consider the following code

```
Manipulate[a,
 Dynamic@Grid[{
    {"Slider", Control[{{a, 0, ""}, 0, 1, .1}]},
    {"Checkbox", Control[{{b, 1, ""}, {1, 0}}]}
    }, Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}],
 Delimiter,
 Button["Button 1"],
 Button["Button 2"],
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

which gives

[image]

Now, if we were to include an `If` statement for one of the buttons, we would need to use `Dynamic`. For example, we could use

```
Manipulate[a,
 Dynamic@Grid[{
    {"Slider", Control[{{a, 0, ""}, 0, 1, .1}]},
    {"Checkbox", Control[{{b, 1, ""}, {1, 0}}]}
    }, Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}],
 Delimiter,
 Button["Button 1"],
 Dynamic[If[a == 0, Button["Button 2"], Button["Button 3"]]],
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

which yields

[image]

As one can see, the button alignment changes when I do this. I want to fix this, to keep the same appearance as in the first example. One attempt at trying to solve this was to consider a `Dynamic@Grid`. That is,

```
Manipulate[a,
 Dynamic@Grid[{
    {"Slider", Control[{{a, 0, ""}, 0, 1, .1}]},
    {"Checkbox", Control[{{b, 1, ""}, {1, 0}}]}
    }, Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}],
 Delimiter,
 Dynamic@Grid[{
    {Button["Button 1"]},
    If[a == 0, {Button["Button 2"]}, {Button["Button 3"]}]
    }],
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

This, however, makes it a bit worse:

[image]

I could change the `ItemSize` within the `Grid` to get something similar to what I want, but I would have to do it manually. For instance,

```
Manipulate[a,
 Dynamic@Grid[{
    {"Slider", Control[{{a, 0, ""}, 0, 1, .1}]},
    {"Checkbox", Control[{{b, 1, ""}, {1, 0}}]}
    }, Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}],
 Delimiter,
 Dynamic@Grid[{
    {Button["Button 1"]},
    If[a == 0, {Button["Button 2"]}, {Button["Button 3"]}]
    }, ItemSize -> 30],
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

leads to

[image]

Still, the alignment with the slider is not perfect, and I'd have to manually adjust it. I wonder if it's possible to do this in a more "automatic" way, without relying on manually fixing the `ItemSize`. I could include all controls in a `Grid`, but the problem with that is that the `Delimiter` doesn't seem to format if I use a `Grid`, and I want to keep it in my `Manipulate`. Any ideas how to solve this?

Furthermore, how would I deal with the case

```
Manipulate[a,
 Dynamic@Grid[{
    {"Slider", Control[{{a, 0, ""}, 0, 1, .1}]},
    {"Checkbox", Control[{{b, 1, ""}, {1, 0}}]}
    }, Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}],
 Delimiter,
 Dynamic@Column[{
    {Button["Button 1"], Button["Button 2"]} // Row,
    {Button["Button 3"], Button["Button 4"]} // Row
    }, ItemSize -> 15],
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

that is,

[image]

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about putting everything in the grid? Like so:

```
Manipulate[a,
  Dynamic @
    Grid[
      {{"Slider", Control[{{a, 0, ""}, 0, 1, .1}]},
       {"Checkbox", Control[{{b, 1, ""}, {1, 0}}]},
       {Button["Button 1"], SpanFromLeft},
       {If[a == 0, Button["Button 2"], Button["Button 3"]], SpanFromLeft}},
      Dividers -> {False, {3 -> True}},
      Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}],
  ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

The result looks like this:

Slider at zero

[image: at_zero]

Slider moved off zero.

[image: off_zero]

#### Update 1

For your array of four buttons, will this work?

```
Manipulate[a,
  Grid[
    {{"Slider", Control[{{a, 0, ""}, 0, 1, .1}]},
     {"Checkbox", Control[{{b, 1, ""}, {1, 0}}]}},
    Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}],
  Delimiter,
  Grid[
    {{Button["Button 1"], Button["Button 2"]},
     {Button["Button 3"], Button["Button 4"]}},
    ItemSize -> {Scaled[.2], Automatic}],
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image: four_buttons]

#### Update 2

You apparently don't like my first attempt at solving your four button array problem because buttons are elastic and change width as adjustments are made to notebook window, while manipulators are rigid and ignore such changes. The only solution I can think of is to make everything rigid. This means that you will have to specify the control sizes in your code and your users will be stuck with what you specify.

```
Manipulate[a,
  Grid[
    {{Item["Slider", ItemSize -> 100/CurrentValue["FontMWidth"]], 
      Control[{{a, 0, ""}, 0, 1, .1, ImageSize -> 300}]},
     {"Checkbox", Control[{{b, 1, ""}, {1, 0}}]}},
    Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}],
  Delimiter,
  Grid[
    {{Button["Button 1", ImageSize -> 180], Button["Button 2", ImageSize -> 180]},
    {Button["Button 3"], Button["Button 4"]}}],
  ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image: four_buttons]

Notes

- My target width for the controls array is 400 points. The buttons are set to 190 points to allow for the spacing between them. The manipulator is set to 290 points for a similar reason.
- The target for the labels is 100 points. However, `ItemSize` works in printer's ems (as redefined by WRI). That is reason for dividing by `CurrentValue["FontMWidth"]`.
- Width specifications need only be set for the top row of a grid. Succeeding rows will follow what was set for the top.

Comment: Thank you. This should work! Also, there is a natural spacing using the `Delimiter`, which I don't get using `Dividers`. This is but a minor detail. Any ideas to improve this? Maybe just use `Spacer`?

Comment: @samwolfe. Adding the option `Spacings -> {Automatic, {3 -> 2}}` to `Grid` looks good to me. Also, I posted an update with a possible answer to four button problem.

Comment: It seems the case of the four buttons doesn't really solve it. They go beyond the slider size, instead of aligning with it.

Comment: Also, the problem with using Dividers is that if I dynamically hide certain Controls, the horizontal line is not correctly updated, unlike the Delimiter, which is always in the correct position. Maybe I could use something like `{Graphics[Line[...]],SpanFromLeft}`? What do you think?

Comment: @samwolfe. See 2nd update for another way of solving the four button problem. As for your new question on how to handle dynamic reconfiguration of the button array, I am afraid that is more of a job than I care to take on.

Comment: Using the two `Grid` options `Spacings -> {Automatic, {3 -> 2}}` and ``Dividers -> {3 -> Manipulate`Dump`$delimitercolor}``  (where ``Manipulate`Dump`$delimitercolor`` is `GrayLevel[0, 0.2]` on Windows 10) we get the default delimiter. (+1)

Comment: Dear m_goldberg and kglr. If you have time, please take a look at the follow up question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212452/dynamic-delimiter-in-manipulate

Comment: @samwolfe. I have read the question you refer to in the above comment. I can't answer it. It seems you are asking for something either very complex or that I don't understand the question.

Comment: Thanks anyway. If you have any suggestion of a "nice-looking" delimiter to use inside the grid directly instead of `Dividers` or the `Delimiter` option itself, please let me know.