# Dynamic Delimiter in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, gui-construction, style

Consider the following

```
Manipulate[a,
 Dynamic@Grid[{
    {"Control 1", Control[{{a, 0, ""}, {1, 0}}]},
    If[a == 1, {"Subcontrol 1", Control[{{aa, 0, ""}, {1, 0}}]}, 
     Unevaluated[Sequence[]]],
    {"Control 2", Control[{{b, 0, ""}, {1, 0}}]}
    },
   Spacings -> {Automatic, {2 -> 1}},
   Dividers -> {False, {2 -> Manipulate`Dump`$delimitercolor}},
   Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}],
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

My goal is to include a dynamic delimiter between the two controls. Since `Delimiter` doesn't seem to work within a `Grid`, an alternative is to use `Spacings` and `Dividers` with the right colouring, as [previously discussed here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211509/multiple-buttons-in-a-manipulate-how-do-i-get-a-good-layout).

This solution, however, doesn't account for possible dynamic changes in the `Control` section. For example, if Control 1 is checked, we get

[image]

As one can see, the divider doesn't change position. A solution would be to make the slight change

```
Spacings -> {Automatic, {2 + a -> 1}},
Dividers -> {False, {2 + a -> Manipulate`Dump`$delimitercolor}}
```

In this manner, the spacings and dividers change accordingly to Control 1 and I get what I want

[image]

However, my code has a great amount of controls of all type, all interconnected and conditioned by `If`s. This would yield a more complex and long manipulation of both `Spacings` and `Dividers`. I'm afraid this might slow down the `Manipulate` interactivity and I feel there must be an easier solution to divider (or delimiter, in my case) positioning.

For example, `Spacings` could be reasonably replaced by something like `{"",""}` or `{Spacer[x],Spacer[x]}` in the `Control` section. Since I want to keep the `Grid` layout, getting the right `Delimiter` look seems somewhat trickier without `Dividers`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do the controls HAVE to appear and disappear? Wouldn't it be preferable to simply have them there all the time in an inactive state, only to be activated when the corresponding master control is active? That would also seem to be better UI design as well; I for one *hate* to hunt around for moving buttons in user interfaces.

Comment: The problem is that there are too many controls in my program, thus some of them expand or collapse sections. It's not ideal, but having all at all times would yield a huge interface, and I want to keep it as clean as possible. I don't like moving buttons/sections constantly as well, but do you have suggestions for better/alternative expanding/collapsing designs?

Comment: Sam, Why not just have them become inactive with a tooltip that describes how to get them to activate? Or some design of that sort, where you could click the inactive box and have other boxes become highlighted or indicated that would be potential combinations to activate the aforementioned clicked inactive box?

Comment: @CATrevillian That would be great too. I'm actually tempted to change my main code to that, and avoid the many `If` expressions I'm using. Do you have any suggestions on how to do that? Anyway, I believe I have found a solution for this specific problem, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime, I believe I have found an answer. Might not be the best one, but I'm sharing it anyway.

One thing we could do is to track the position of the specific section I want to delimit. One can do that using `Position`. In my case, I want to track Control 2. Thus, defining the `Grid` as `grid` and Control 2 as `ctr2`, the following code does what I want

```
Manipulate[a,
 Dynamic@Grid[gri = {
     {"Control 1", Control[{{a, 0, ""}, {1, 0}}]},
     If[a == 1, {"Subcontrol 1", Control[{{aa, 0, ""}, {1, 0}}]}, 
      Unevaluated[Sequence[]]],
     ctr2 = {"Control 2", Control[{{b, 0, ""}, {1, 0}}]}
     },
   Spacings -> {Automatic, {Position[gri, ctr2][[1, 1]] -> 1}},
   Dividers -> {False, {Position[gri, ctr2][[1, 1]] -> 
       Manipulate`Dump`$delimitercolor}},
   Alignment -> {{Right, Left}, Automatic}],
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

Any improvements/suggestions are welcome.